# 2 hot water heaters (gas) in series

Tags: plumbing-fixture

1. Is there any advantage in heating the first hot water for recovery time in the second ?
2. Do I only have the available hot water in the second for delivery to the fixtures ? 
   I did not install this but assume the goal was more hot water.
3. Is the only way to achieve more hot water, convert the plumbing to parallel ?

Comment: More hot water - undersized water heater ? say 40 gallon instead of 75 gallon ? Tankless - gives plenty of hot water, or a larger tank. The inline system raises water temperature first making it easier (faster) to get from the inlet temp on the second unit to the desired temp (recovery time is sped up). It does not really supply more hot water. More comes from a bigger tank , it appears to be more with 2 tanks because of a fast recovery time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a very clear advantage.  Use the first tank to take the water from street temperature to say around 90*.  Use the second tank to take it form 90* to the 120* or whatever temp you want at the tap.  You will have considerable more capacity.  There are a number of additional advantages as well.  Happy Heating.  P.

Comment: Thanks, I take care of this house and the complaint is always not enough hot water.

Comment: Also a win  if you're a bio-terrorist trying to breed legionella.   That will really do it!

Comment: Raising the temperature by adjusting the thermostat is an easy way to increase "capacity". When the water is hotter you generally use less over a given time period (depends on how you use it, of course).

Comment: @JimmyFix-it raising the temperature to higher than 120F is a dangerous scalding risk unless there are anti-scald or mixing devices installed on every hot water faucet.

Comment: Yup, scalding has been a risk with use of heated water since time immemorial, one must be careful. BTW most anti-scald features will **not** protect you if you raise the water temperature (unless you adjust them), as they rely on mix limits set at the time of installation and/or pressure fluctuation. Only the newest/most expensive types use a thermostatic mixing control.

Comment: In my place, there's a mixing valve on the tank itself...

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of Having 2 Water Heaters

1. Higher hot water capacity for your house, both in hot water volume stored and a faster recovery rate.
2. Backup redundancy for your entire home if one water heater fails and must be replaced, provided that you do the necessary plumbing to run the two water heaters IN PARALLEL, NOT IN SERIES, as some people suggest.

For the redundancy advantage. When your single water heater totally craps out or starts leaking on a Sunday afternoon, which is usually the case, you may be without hot water for days or weeks due to scheduling a plumber, supply chain disruptions, etc. With 2 water heaters IN PARALLEL, it takes less than a minute to keep on living normally by doing these steps:

1. Turn off the heat source of the malfunctioning water heater, either by opening its circuit breaker (electric), or by turning the water thermostat thermostat to OFF and shutting its gas supply valve.
2. Shut the water heater water inlet supply valve and the water heater water outlet valve of the malfunctioning water heater. Leave the water heater cross connect valve open so that the working water heater will supply all of your home's hot water until you can get the defective one replaced.

Note: One advantage of the cross connect valve is the ability to close it if you have teenagers who like to take "hotel showers." At least then they would not have an unlimited supply of hot water, but would run out when the water heater of a split system ran out.